# How to do cross verification of pandas column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe like below.

```
index  thread twod
  1    a    b
  2    c    d
  3    a    e
  4    b    a 
  5    d    c
```

And i want the out but like below

```
index   thread twod correlation
   1       a    b      2-way
   2       c    d      2-way
   3       a    e      1-way
   4       b    a      2-way
   5       d    c      2-way
```

Here 2-way is decided by if col_A value is present in col_B and its col_A value present in col_B of where it is occurred like check index 1 and 4 or 2 and 5.

````
import numpy as np
for i in enumerate(threed):
    if i[1] in twod:
        index1=twod.index(i[1])
        #print(i[1],index1)
        if threed[index1] == twod[i[0]]:
            s.add(index1)
s=list(s)            
df=df.reset_index()        
df['correation']=np.where(df['index'].isin(s),'2-way','1-way') ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use, [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) along axis 1 to create a series `s` which contains immutable set pairs of group `thread & twod` then use `groupby` to group this series on itself and then use transform to calculate the size of each group:

```
s = df[['thread', 'twod']].agg(frozenset, axis=1)
df['correlation'] = s.groupby(s).transform('size').astype(str) + '-way'
```

---

```
# print(df)
  thread twod correlation
0      a    b       2-way
1      c    d       2-way
2      a    e       1-way
3      b    a       2-way
4      d    c       2-way
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `pandas.Series.isin`:

```
s1, s2 = df["thread"], df["twod"]
df["correlation"] = (s1.isin(s2).astype(int) + s2.isin(s1).astype(int)).astype(str) + "-way"
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   index thread twod correlation
0      1      a    b       2-way
1      2      c    d       2-way
2      3      a    e       1-way
3      4      b    a       2-way
4      5      d    c       2-way
```

Answer (score 0):

If need to counts by sorted pairs use `np.sort` with `DataFrame` constructor and then count by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df[['thread', 'twod']].to_numpy(), axis=1), index=df.index)

df['correlation'] = df1.groupby([0,1])[0].transform('size').astype(str) + '-way'
print (df)
  thread twod correlation
1      a    b       2-way
2      c    d       2-way
3      a    e       1-way
4      b    a       2-way
5      d    c       2-way
```